# Installing libsodium in MAMP environment

Tags: mamp, pecl, libsodium

I'm trying to install libsodium (following this guide https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/00-intro.md#installing-libsodium). When I attempt to use pecl install libsodium, I get the following result:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/libsodium.so'
ERROR: failed to write /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/libsodium.so (copy(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/libsodium.so): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted)
```

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working, and how I can overcome it?

Comment: you might find some ideas here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory. At first sight it seems that you don't have authorization to write to that directory

Answer (score 0):

I installed libsodium on MAMP using PECL.
It's easy when everything is configured.

Basically you just need to

1. check this checkbox on MAMP > PHP. Make sure to open a new terminal tab or restart it to make effect.
   [image]
2. Run `pecl install libsodium` and follow the latest instruction
   [image]

## Troubleshooting

I faced an issue related to GNU (autom4te: need GNU m4 1.4 or later: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/m4)  when trying to install with PECL.

I solved it by following [these steps](https://superuser.com/a/1364847/116701) after `brew install m4`.

Also, make sure xcode is installed and using latest versions (`xcode-select --install`).

I hope it helps.